# Getting impression/click/cost data for other search engines from analytics reporting api v4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

We recently updated our analytics reporting API from version 3 to version 4 and noticed that the impression/click/cost data that we import into google analytics in the admin tab is no longer coming through with the ga:adcost,ga:impressions,ga:adclicks metrics in the api. In the documentation for the API it looks like those fields are listed under the dimensions and metrics for Adwords. Does this mean that this data won't come through the api for other publishers?

hopefully someone else has some experience with this or a potential workaround. We really need our data coming through for bing ads, yahoo gemini, etc.